# Java to VB.Net Conversion of This Function

Tags: java, vb.net, code-snippets, sha1, encryption

I have a Java snippet here, I was wondering if it is possible to translate to VB.Net, as I have no found a snippet for VB.Net - only this:

```
    private static byte[] SHA1(final String in)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        md.update(in.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), 0, in.length());
        return md.digest();
    }

    public static String decryptSHA1(String key, final String start) {
        final String delim = "a";
        if (start == null)
            return null;
        byte[] hashedkey;
        byte[] password;
        int i;
        try {
            hashedkey = SHA1(key);
        } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return start;
        } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return start;
        }
        final String[] temp = start.split(delim);
        password = new byte[temp.length];
        for (i = 0; i < hashedkey.length; i++) {
            final int temp2 = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
            if (hashedkey[i] == temp2) {
                break;
            } else {
                password[i] = (byte) (temp2 - hashedkey[i]);
            }
        }
        return new String(password, 0, i);
    }
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It's possible to translate anything to VB.Net. But C# would be easier - any reason why you can't use that?

Comment: A C# conversion would suffice, just Java I have no experience with whatsoever.

Comment: Rather than a line-by-line port of a function (or two) from one language to another... How about an understanding of what the function is doing and implementing it directly in the desired language?  (Which may have built-in functionality which can be used.)

Comment: I have researched, and SHA1 is not supposed to be decrypted so there is no resources apart from this one that I found - hence needing it translated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hardest part here seems to be redoing the SHA1 method.  You just need to find the equivalent .NET library classes/methods.  Judging from the names, you probably want the [System.Text.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class and the [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1.aspx) class.  Off hand, the algorithm probably ends up something like this

```
Private Shared Function SHA1(input As String) As Byte()
    Dim iso8859 = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")
    Dim inBytes = ios8859.GetBytes(input)
    ' This is one implementation of the abstract class SHA1.'
    Dim sha As New SHA1CryptoServiceProvider()
    Return sha.ComputeHash(data)
End Function
```

From there you should be able to convert the rest of the `decryptSHA1` function yourself as it is just basic byte manipulation.  I will note that the `GetEncoding` function says it throws `ArgumentException` if you pass an invalid code page name and there does not seem to be any equivalent exception for `NoSuchAlgorithmException` to worry about catching.